# Php query don't work with mysqli_query() but work on php my admin

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Im trying to use this query on php with mysqli_query():

```
$query = 
    ("
                SELECT
                    COALESCE(
                        (
                            SELECT
                                indicadores_respostas.resposta_text
                            FROM
                                indicadores_respostas
                                LEFT JOIN indicadores_secoes_itens ON indicadores_secoes_itens.id = indicadores_respostas.id_secao_item
                            WHERE
                                indicadores_respostas.id_indicador = indicadores.id
                                AND indicadores_secoes_itens.titulo = 'Longitude'
                        ),
                        (
                            SELECT
                                cidades.longitude
                            FROM
                                cidades
                                INNER JOIN indicadores_respostas
                                LEFT JOIN indicadores_secoes_itens ON indicadores_secoes_itens.id = indicadores_respostas.id_secao_item
                            WHERE
                                indicadores.id = indicadores_respostas.id_indicador
                                AND cidades.cidades_id = CAST(indicadores_respostas.resposta_text AS SIGNED)
                                AND indicadores_secoes_itens.titulo = 'Cidade'
                        )
                    ) AS Longitude
                FROM
                    indicadores
                    LEFT JOIN indicadores_respostas ON indicadores_respostas.id_indicador = indicadores.id
                    LEFT JOIN indicadores_secoes_itens ON indicadores_secoes_itens.id = indicadores_respostas.id_secao_item
                WHERE
                    indicadores_secoes_itens.titulo = 'Nome da capacitação' OR indicadores_secoes_itens.titulo = 'Instituição'
    ");

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

But in Php its returning me 0 rows, but the exactly same query on PHP my admin, in the same database, return 2 rows

[image]

someone know what am I doing wrong?

Here is my connection string:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_db", "3308");
```

OBS: $Result is returning true and if I made some more "gereric" query, like

```
SELECT * FROM Cidades
```

that works normally

MORE INFORMATION:

with or without try catch, my return is

[image]

Comment: Please post the other parts of the database code also. 

My ideas: 
Is mysql_query returning a mysql_result object with 0 rows is it returning FALSE?  And an PHP error?  
If the connect fails or something else geoes wrong in the php file you will get FALSE with an PHP error.  
Did you check that? 
Did you check the  **error.log** ?   
Please also check if  mysqli_error()  if the result should be false.

Comment: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` doesn't do anything. You need `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: I've completed my question with these informations, but anyway, yes, I checked, 0 errors, $result is true, and if I wrote a smaller query like select * from cidades, works

Comment: What is the point of that `try` statement? Why do you need it? Can you remove it to see if it is the reason why you can't see errors

Comment: Have you got the correct connection charset set? i.e. `utf8mb4`?

Comment: yes, utf8_general_ci

Comment: No, not the table/column collation. I meant connection charset

Comment: Have you read in the manual the examples? https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php They show the 3 steps necessary to establish the connection properly.

Comment: worked with "mysqli_set_charset($connection ,"utf8mb4");" you're right, seems strange to me other querys working, and I didn't tried that. Thank You man!

Comment: Basics: Are you certain you are using the same credentials and the same database in the phpMyAdmin page? You can turn on verbose mysql query logging to see if these are in fact executing identically.

Comment: One explanation:  Possibly the other queries working like the general  "SELECT * FROM Cidades  without the proper charset  have no special charcters like in the last line.    ---  indicadores_secoes_itens.titulo = 'Nome da capacitação' OR indicadores_secoes_itens.titulo = 'Instituição' ----   so these 2 chars  may be the problem:  **çã**  unless you have the correct charset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to connect using mysqli involves 3 steps: enabling error reporting, creating an instance of mysqli class, and setting the correct charset.

The example taken from [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) demonstrates these steps:

```
<?php

/* You should enable error reporting for mysqli before attempting to make a connection */
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

/* Set the desired charset after establishing a connection */
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8mb4');
```

Most of the time the correct charset is `utf8mb4`, but you might be using a different one. If you are still using the deprecated one called `utf8` I recommend you change it as soon as possible.

The proper charset ensures that MySQL understands the character encoding used by the client. Phrases like `'Nome da capacitação'` might be encoded differently when using different charsets and MySQL will return no matching results if you use incorrect charset. You have to make sure that the connection charset matches the one used in the table collation. As a best practice, I strongly recommend you stick to using `utf8mb4` everywhere.